# If cell is empty delete sheet in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting, xlsx

$worksheet is the current sheet, $WorkBook has been defined as the path to the xlsx file.

Here is my code:

```
if($worksheet.Cells.Item(1,3).text -eq ""){
    $WorkBook.worksheets.Item("DeleteThisSheet").Delete()
}
```

I'm trying to delete the current sheet, "DeleteThisSheet" if cell A3 is empty.

I'm not getting any errors and not getting any results either. I'm thinking my -eq "" may not be the proper way to identify an empty cell?

Comment: try `If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,3).value2)){` and see if that works better for you.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that worked. Go ahead an post as an answer and I'll give you credit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks for a null or empty value, and references the `Value2` property of the cell instead of the `Text` property. I have the most luck dealing with that, as it is the actual value of a cell instead of a calculated property.

```
If([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,3).value2)){
```